# React Redux nested Component Mui TextField doesn't update with state change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I'm struggling getting a react / redux state component refreshed

the content I want to display gets processed as expected.
I pick it up in the component via redux useSelector hook.

```
const content = useSelector(my.select.content, helper.customEqual);
```

the component displays a title, a box which gets dynamically built based on the content.

- The title and the div-block refresh as expected
- The TextField (is MaterialTextField, see below) :

  - defaultValue doesnt refresh, if key does/n't exist the field is added with the correct value / removed
  - label does refresh

```
<Typography variant="headline" component="h3">
  {title}: {content.label  } 
</Typography>
<Box
  component="form"
>
  {
    Object.keys(content)
    .map(key => {
      return (
        <Typography color="textSecondary">
          <div>{key}: {content[key]  /* this refreshes */} </div>
          <TextField
    
            label={content[key]}  /* should be:  label={key} */  
            defaultValue={content[key] }
          />
        </Typography>
      )
    })
  }
</Box>
```

For completeness, (Mui) TextField is a Atom, I don't see a react/redux related issue here, but possibly if the id exists with the same value it doesn't rerender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging while typing the question revealed that it is indeed a Mui related misconfiguration in [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/).

```
defaultValue    any     The default value. Use when the component is not controlled.
value           any     The value of the input element, required for a controlled component.
```

switching to `value` did the job.